# Filtering an evaluated QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models

I am evaluating one QuerySet, and then another, but the second is a subset of the first. I'm trying to do this in an efficient way, with as few database calls as possible. (This has been asked before but to be honest I didn't totally understand the answer and I'm not sure they completely apply to what I'm thinking about.)

Using the Django doc's [example Weblog models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#queryset-model-example), in a view, this is the code before trying to optimise:

```
myblog = Blog.objects.get(pk=1)

d={} #going to pass this to my template

# not using count()
d['num_of_entries'] = len(myblog.entry_set.all()) 

# not using exists()
d['is_jolly'] = bool(Entry.objects.filter(blog=myblog, headline__startswith='Jolly'))

# ... other code but no further use of database in this view
```

The second QuerySet is a subset of the first. Should I try to use pure Python to get the subset (and so only evaluate one QuerySet -one less database call)?

Or, perhaps simply do the following?

```
# other code as above

d['num_of_entries'] = myblog.entry_set.count()

d['is_jolly'] = Entry.objects.filter(blog=myblog, headline__startswith='Jolly').exists()

# ... other code but no further use of database in this view
```

Comment: in your second example you can write:
`d['is_jolly'] = myblog.entry_set.filter(headline__startswith='Jolly').exists()`

Comment: would that result in fewer database calls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"As few database queries as possible" isn't the right criterion. You want to also think about the *amount of work* done by those database queries, and the *amount of data that's transferred* from the database to your Django server.

Let's consider the two ways to implement what you're after. Approach 1:

```
entries = myblog.entry_set.all()
num_of_entries = len(entries)
is_jolly = any(e.headline.startswith('Jolly') for e in entries)
```

Approach 2:

```
num_of_entries = myblog.entry_set.count()
is_jolly = Entry.objects.filter(blog=myblog, headline__startswith='Jolly').exists()
```

In approach 1 there's a single database query, but that query going to be something like `SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE ...`. It potentially fetches a *large number of entries*, and transmits *all their content* across the network to your Django server, which then throws nearly all that content away (the only field it actually looks at is the `headline` field).

In approach 2 there are two database queries, but the first one is a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ENTRY WHERE ...` which fetches just one integer, and the second is a `SELECT EXISTS(...)` which fetches just one Boolean. Since these queries don't have to fetch all the matching entries, there are a lot more possibilities for the database to optimize the queries.

So approach 2 looks much better in this case, even though it issues more queries.

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#exists) say "calling QuerySet.exists() is faster than bool(some_query_set), but not by a large degree." However in my case (SQLite) it results in a query which ends with `LIMIT 1` -which sounds like what you mentioned -so do the docs sounds wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment question. For me (using SQLite) `QuerySet.exists()` results in `SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM foo WHERE bar LIMIT 1` -rather than `EXISTS`. What I meant was, given that `bool(Entry.objects.filter(blog=myblog, headline__startswith='Jolly'))` potentially fetches a large number of results, where the docs state "calling QuerySet.exists() is faster than bool(some_query_set), but not by a large degree.", can this be correct?

Comment: Oh yes, I see now: the same queries are generated on MySQL. So I agree, the docs seem to be misleading on this point. You should [submit a bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket).

Comment: Not sure if it's what you had in mind but I [opened a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19630#ticket)

Comment: would your advice to use approach 2 rather than approach 1 still apply if Entry only had two fields?